# Live updating message in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have been learning python for a few weeks now, and decided to get into tkinter and GUI scripting. It is easy enough to follow along with tutorials, but the best way to learn is by doing it yourself. I decided to make a simple press the button get money, and it is all set up, but I cannot have it print out a live update of how many points you have. If anyone could help me that would be swell. Thanks in advance! :)

P.S. everything works except for the "you have somthing money" part so don't question the rest. It is referenced in other parts

```
class SellPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        WelcomePage.configure(self, background='#08FFC7')

        def makeMoney():
            x = random.randint(1,100)
            global money
            if x == 100:
                money = money + 5
            else:
                money = money + 1

        label1 = ttk.Label(self, text="Begin making money!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label1.pack()
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Make money!", command=makeMoney)
        button1.pack()
        label2 = ttk.Label(self, text="You have "+str(money)+" dollars!")
        label2.pack()
```

Comment: You could use `label2.configure(text='new_amount')` inside `makeMoney`. And instead of using a global variable for `money`, you could use an attribute (`self.money`).

Comment: Thanks, the label worked, but the reason I am using global money is as I need to access it in another class. Thanks for your help.